# MVVM Binding for Control Text

Tags: mvvm

I've got a Silverlight client and I'm using MVVM. I've put in my first View and View Model. The View binds to the View Model. I now want to localise the text of all the controls. For example my View has a button which contains the text "Search". I know I need to bind the Text content property of the button to something to provide the correct text. The question is what? Do I provide a property in the View Model called SearchButtonText and bind it to that(where the SearchButtonText property returns a resource string)? Or is this taking it too far in terms of what the View Model does and instead bind to a resource string in the View namespace, even though the root level binding for the View is the View Model?

Any help much appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind to a resource string in the view.